# Passing a form as an argument in javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, arguments, forms

I am trying to pass a form as an argument in a function. This is not the only form on that page. I am not sure if this is the right way to pass the form and consume it. Here is my code snippet.

```
echo "<form action='/index.php/Taxbrowser_Taxonpage'  name='speciesSpecForm' id='speciesSpecForm' target='_blank'>";
echo '<table class="alignTop" width="700px"><tr><td>';
foreach ($ties as $tie) {
echo "<a href='/index.php/Taxbrowser_Taxonpage?taxon={$tie}' onclick='return waitingDialog(this.form,this.href)'><em>{$tie}</em></a></br>";
if ($i == $col1max || $i == $col2max) {
    echo '</td><td>';
}
$i++;
}
echo '</td></tr></table></form>';
```

And my function looks like this,

```
function waitingDialog(form,url) {
        invokeAction(form, url, 'popup', 1024, 640, '', 'Tree Based Identification', 'Working', '');
        return false;
}
```

invokeAction function looks like this,

```
function invokeAction(payload, destination, destinationType, popupWidth, popupHeight, windowName, title, message){

var toType = function(obj) {
     return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
}

//Since Javascript doesn't have default values this check sets default values if they are not present
payload = typeof payload != 'undefined' ? payload : '';
destination = typeof destination != 'undefined' ? destination : '';
destinationType = typeof destinationType != 'undefined' ? destinationType : 'nopopup';
popupHeight = typeof popupHeight != 'undefined' ? popupHeight : 1024;
popupWidth = typeof popupWidth != 'undefined' ? popupWidth : 768;
windowName = typeof windowName != 'undefined' ? windowName : 'popupWin';
title = typeof title != 'undefined' ? title : 'Loading';
message = typeof message != 'undefined' ? message : '';

if(title.length > 71){
    title = title.substring(0, 68) + "...";
}
if (destinationType == "nopopup"){
    showWaitingDialogBox(title,message);

    if (destination != ""){
        if (toType(payload) == 'object') {
            $(payload).attr('action', destination);
        } else {
            $('form[name="'+payload+'"]').attr('action', destination);
        }
    }
    if (toType(payload) == 'object') {
        $(payload).attr("target",'_self');
        $(payload).submit();
    } else {
        $('form[name="'+payload+'"]').attr('target', '_self');
        $('form[name="'+payload+'"]').submit();
    }
} else { //handles popup and others
    //check if a window with the same destinationType exists
    if (destinationType != null){
        destinationType = destinationType + "1";
    } 
    popup = window.open('/index.php/Working', destinationType,'scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width='+popupWidth+',height='+popupHeight);
    popup.focus();
    //e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function(){

        if (destination != ""){
            if (toType(payload) == 'object') {
                $(payload).attr('action', destination);
            } else {
                $('form[name="'+payload+'"]').attr('action', destination);
            }
        } 
        if (toType(payload) == 'object') {
            $(payload).attr("target",destinationType);
            $(payload).submit();
        } else {
            $('form[name="'+payload+'"]').attr('target', destinationType);
            $('form[name="'+payload+'"]').submit();
        }
    },
    450);
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you using a form? There are no inputs?

Comment: @PiX06 For 'invokeAction' function, there should be a form in the argument. So, it's more like a  dummy form. Can you tell me what could be the alternate way? Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code for the invokeAction function so we can see what it does with the passed parameters?

Comment: @PiX06 I have added in the question.

Comment: @PiX06 Just wondering can you think of a reason why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link which solves a problem similar to yours. Basically, this.form is can not be referenced from elements that are not form elements (in your example an  tag). You could have done it from other input elements. A better way to approach will be to use getElementById()

https://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/4294780.htm

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the solution:

```
echo "<a  onclick=\"waitingDialog($(this).parents('form'),'/index.php/Taxbrowser_Taxonpage?taxon={$tie}')\"><em>{$tie}</em></a></br>";
```